# Should I open a JDBC connection for each rest call?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am dealing with high traffic in my Spring Boot project and my goal is serving clients as much fast as possible. In this case, I have more than 500 requests per second. In each rest endpoint call, I should connect my schema and gather multiple information from multiple tables. To be able to do that, should I create new connection for each eendpoint call or create & close before each db query?

I wrote a JDBC connection class but I am not sure that it is a good way. Maybe you can give me some opinion.

## JDBC Connection Class

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@Configuration
public class FraudJDBConfiguration {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(FraudJDBConfiguration.class);

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public FraudJDBConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public Connection getFraudConnection() {
        // Step 1: Loading or
        // registering Oracle JDBC driver class
        String connectionClass = env.getProperty("fraud.db.driver-class-name");
        try {
            Class.forName(connectionClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
            LOGGER.error(cnfex.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("JDBC driver class'ı bulunamadı");
        }

        // Step 2: Opening database connection
        try {
            String environmentType = env.getProperty("environment");
            if (environmentType == null) {
                LOGGER.error("environment Tip Hatası (TEST - UAT - LIVE)");
                throw new RuntimeException("environment Tip Hatası (TEST - UAT - LIVE)");
            } else {
                String connectionString = null;
                String username = null;
                String password = null;
                switch (environmentType.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "dev":
                        connectionString = env.getProperty(/*someurl*/);
                        username = env.getProperty(/*someusername*/);
                        password = env.getProperty(/*somepassword*/);
                        break;
                    case "tst":
                        connectionString = env.getProperty(/*someurl*/);
                        username = env.getProperty(/*someusername*/);
                        password = env.getProperty(/*somepassword*/);
                        break;
                    case "liv":
                        connectionString = env.getProperty(/*someurl*/);
                        username = env.getProperty(/*someusername*/);
                        password = env.getProperty(/*somepassword*/);
                        break;
                    case "uat":
                        connectionString = env.getProperty(/*someurl*/);
                        username = env.getProperty(/*someusername*/);
                        password = env.getProperty(/*somepassword*/);
                        break;
                }
                // Step 2.A: Create and
                // get connection using DriverManager class
                if (connectionString == null) {
                    LOGGER.error("fraud şeması için connection string bulunamadı");
                    throw new RuntimeException("fraud şeması için connection string bulunamadı");
                }
                return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## DAO

```
@Component
public interface FraudCommTransactionsDao {
    Long count();
}
```

## DAO IMPL

```
@Service
public class FraudCommTransactionsDaoImpl implements FraudCommTransactionsDao {
    private final FraudJDBConfiguration fraudJDBConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public FraudCommTransactionsDaoImpl(FraudJDBConfiguration fraudJDBConfiguration) {
        this.fraudJDBConfiguration = fraudJDBConfiguration;
    }

    @Override
    public Long count() {
        try(Connection connection = fraudJDBConfiguration.getFraudConnection()) {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(/*some query*/);

            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getLong("transaction_id");
            } else {
                return 0L;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a bad idea, use a datasource instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will look it up.

Comment: Please read about Spring Boot and connection pooling: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Move the connection cache inside the datasource.  Look into c3p0.

Comment: Your JDBC connection doesn't appear to be dependent on user credentials, so connection pooling would work far better than making a connection per request.

Comment: Spring Boot provides datasources with connection pools and the right methods for providing environment specific configurations. Why are you using `DriverManager`? And why are you trying to do in code what Spring Boot can already provide for you? And to be blunt, Spring Boot itself handles this better than your code does.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov When using connection pooling properly, one will create a (logical) connection per request. That logical connection will just be backed by an existing physical connection from the connection pool. And upon closing the logical connection, the physical connection becomes available for reuse. That however is still a 'connection per request' model from the perspective of the consumer (user of the connection).

Comment: This seems to be a mess of Spring mistakes and midunderstanding. I would recommend, in the strongest possible terms, that you read a basic Spring tutorial before tackling writing a non-trivial application. Discard what you have written and start here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 1):

No, establishing a new physical connection to a database server is costly. It involves multiple steps: user authorization, establishing session defaults, allocating memory on both client and server, etc. This overhead should not be added to every single request.

It's a common practice to create a [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) to share the physical connections between application threads. This introduces a concept of logical connections e.g. a `Connection` object created with `DriverManager.getConnection()` is a physical connection while `DataSource.getConnection()` returns a logical connection which is a proxy.

There are multiple database connection pooling libraries for Java that you can use e.g. [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/). Don't write your own, this is [not simple](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Bad-Behavior:-Handling-Database-Down).

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct - it is the answer to an XY problem. The OP needs to follow a basic Spring tutorial before playing around with connection pools. Spring handles all of this by default.

Answer (score -1):

Get fast data and deliver to client could be possible using the simplest way of using application.properties file. You may use this to get database connection to your datasource.